# Lightning Web Components licence fee

Tags: lightning-web-components, appexchange

Lightning Web Components have been released a while ago. However, there seems only limited information on how you can use it for business purposes.

I wonder if I need to pay licence fee or anything to sell an app built with LWC on AppExchange and other platforms.

My second question is whether using LWC or existing Aura component for commercial app makes any differences in terms of license fee, subscribers' access to salesforce platform when it is sold on AppExchange.

I Looked at official documentation but could not find the answers to these questions. Any helpful web-site links are welcomed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess not. Everything that comes with the Aura and LWC platforms is included in the license fees customers pay for their Salesforce orgs. And whatever you distribute through AppExchange is subject to the terms of ISV partnership.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Is there any way to see if I can distribute my app built with LWC on other platforms and if possible, what permission/licence would be like.

Comment: What kind of platforms are you thinking of?

Comment: I am thinking of Google Cloud Platform right now but possibly other platforms too.

Comment: If you are planning to use the open-source parts of LWC then refer to the license for that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.